# Hiding table ID's in a website

Tags: php

I'm building a php website with lots of jquery / ajax.  Basically the site is a simple blog and I display the last 10 database entries and their corresponding headlines on the front page.  The user is then able to click a headline (where it's rerouted to site.com/blog?cid=76) and then view the full blog entry.

basically, is there any database security risk with displaying the 76 which corresponds to the blog_id in the database?  Should I be making things more secure and if so how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Short answer: No. I'm sure someone less asleep than me will be kind enough to provide a long answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why would this be a security issue if your users could access this site anyway?

Comment: I don't see any security issue, though it'd be nice from a UX/SEO POV if the URL was the article title rather than a number

Comment: sorry, I should clarify: is there any database security risk by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no security issue.

It is similar to telling us what id this post has:

stackoverflow.com/questions/**11379226**/hiding-table-ids-in-a-website

All it does is tell the user which post it is.

Answer (score 1):

The way you implemented it forces you to pass the id of the blog entry anyway: be it in POST or in a GET request. If the application is secure enough there shouldn't be a problem with passing the id. The only thing you could do would be to make the id a little bit more obscurely passed in the GET request:

Something like: site.com/blogs/disp/76 for instance

Comment: +1 for suggesting friendlier URLs. The OP should look into mod-rewrite, or CMSs (almost all of which automate this sort of URL window dressing).

Comment: if I may ask, what does CMS stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are risks. You need to know about und understand SQL injection. PHP offers a couple of methods that you can use to help prevent this type of attack.

This site offers a good explanation of SQL injection and methods to help prevent it:

http://rosstanner.co.uk/2012/01/php-mysql-preventing-mysql-injection/

Comment: SQL injection is a risk associated with bad code that allows direct, unbound injunction of post/GET vars into SQL, not a risk associated with IDs being referenced in URLs

Comment: OP stated in a comment that he meant risks with database. He means referencing ID in a database table.